# Fast Algorithms for seeing if a State is Reachable

Tags: optimization, artificial-intelligence

I have a problem where I have a 2 dimensional map, an initial state and a goal state (typical space state problem). I solved it using A*, I had no problem with that, but I can't seem to find good algorithms that take the initial state, goal state and say if it is solvable (if the goal state is reachable from the initial state). To give more context, this is the kind of problem I solved with A*:

```
0120000000 
0111101111
0000100001
0101111101
0101100001
0101101111
0111100111
0000000000
0111010110
0000000110
```

where 0 = empty tiles, 1 = blocked tiles, 2 = treasure, and the bot could be in any empty tile.

Are there any algorithms that do that? (preferably faster than A*)

Comment: The efficiency of A* depends on the used heuristic function.

Answer (score 1):

You could preprocess the map, labelling all the connected components. Then the reachability test will just need to compare labels.

```cpp
void LabelConnectedComponents(const char ** map, int w, int h)
{
    char component = 'a';
    for (int y = 0; y != h; ++y)
    for (int x = 0; x != w; ++x)
    {
        if (map[y][x] == '0')
            FloodFill(map, w, h, x, y, component++);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple bfs or dfs here, start from starting node and keep its neighbors, where we can move. Then choose one of the kept nodes and keep in the same collection its neighbors which isn't saved yet, as we go through each node, mark them as visited nodes. when we finish we only check whether destination node is marked or not and that's it.